# JavaScript call iFrame location with two approaches, two behaviors... why

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've had a couple projects where I've tried to use both of these lines of code to call the url of an iFrame. They behave differently in IE9+ and FF (IE7 and IE8 work with the first line perfectly.. I have not tested the second line in IE7 and IE8).

Does anyone know why this is? I would imagine it has to do the the IE webkit or something? but, I'm not sure.

```
// This calls the iFrame once, but if you call it again with this command, it throws
// a null object error
window.frames["el"].location 

//versus 

// This seems to work the same each time.
document.getElementById("el").src
```

Any insight would be cool... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method, `frames` accesses a window directly, and reads the live location property. It has only one limitation: When the frame's origin is different, it fails.

The second method reads the src **attribute** of a frame. It's not updated when the frame navigates away. This property is therefore unreliable.

Another option is to read `location` from the frame's `contentWindow` property. It has the same limitations as the first method, but you don't have to attach a `name` attribute to the frame.

```
document.getElementById("el").contentWindow.location
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. This is really good information. Is there a reliable option to read the location (or URL) of an iframe at any given time regardless if it changes multiple times? Or are we stuck with the options you gave here for now?

Comment: Also, what if the only thing that changes about the source is a query string parameter? so, in http://somedomain.com?id=123 ... id would be the only thing that changes... is there a reliable what of getting that information?

Comment: @wakurth The [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) object **always** shows the actual location. It is very reliable. [unless the origin differs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). If the pages are at different domains, and you've got control over both domains and not worry about IE7- support, you can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to pass the actual location to the parent/top window.